# Symfony4 Deployment with Encore

Tags: deployment, symfony4, webpack-encore

The current [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html) says, that I only need the files under `public/build`, created with `./node_modules/.bin/encore production`, when I want to deploy for production. But also to add `public/build` to git ignore. Do I have to copy the content of `public/build` manually?

In Symfony3 my deploy looked like that:

`git pull
bin/php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
bin/php bin/console assets:install --env=prod
bin/php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Using assetic was the »old« way, and starting Symfony 2.8 Assetic is not included in the standard framework anymore (but you can still add it).

Regarding `public/build` you misunderstood it a bit - the actual source files should be somewhere else, for example in `assets/css/app.scss` and `assets/js/app.js`. Using Webpack Encore, running `./node_modules/.bin/encore production` will minify, uglify, etc (whatever you configure in `webpack.config.js`) these source files and then copy the generated files to `public/build`. So `public/build` will only contain the generated stuff and thus can be safely added to `.gitignore` (but you also need to run the encore script in production).

Your JavaScript file (i.e. in this case `app.js`) should include

```
require('../css/app.scss');
```

so that the `app.scss` is actually a dependency of `app.js` and you only need to tell the `webpack.config.js` to include the JavaScript file. The basic configuration of `webpack.config.js` might look like this:

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // this will put all your compiled stuff into public/build, that’s
    // why you can put this into .gitignore, because you can re-build this
    // from the source files.
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    // this will create public/build/app.js, and also public/build/app.css
    // since the scss file is a dependency of app.js
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    // allow sass/scss files to be processed
    .enableSassLoader()

    [...]
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

You can find some more explanation under https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html (first example) or https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html (overview)